# (Rails Active Record): Request with constraint for uniqueness of a filed of the result objects

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Ok, I got the following simple model class:

```
class Baby < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :born_at
  ...
end
```

And I need to collect the youngest 20 babies with unique names

```
Baby.all(:order => "born_at desc", :limit => 20)
```

But I don't know what to add to the request so the names of the babies to be unique.

*Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to SQL databases, so don't judge me for my lame question.*

Comment: Do you need just the names or the whole records?

Answer (score 1):

```
  Baby.group(:name).order('born_at desc').limit(20)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Baby.all(:order => 'born_at desc', :limit => 20, :group => :name)
```

Or if you need only names

```
Baby.select(:name).limit(20).order('born_at desc')
```